# File permissions after module update

Tags: 7, users, updating

Everytime I update a module the (linux) file permissions are changed. I use 755 permissions for my directories and 644 for files inside the modules directory.
Is there anyway I can tell drupal the default file permissions for every module update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that default file permissions on a gnu/linux system come from `/etc/profile` where you can find a line like :

```
umask 022
```

This means all the files will be created with the default 755 file permissions.

However if this is not the case you should check whether you are running your php code along with suPHP since it sets it's own file permissions default and this effectively overrides the ones on `/etc/profile` (usually under `/etc/suphp.conf`).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not Drupal's fault. Check the default file permissions on your server!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "check the default file permissions" part ?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html is an older article but it's nicely written and quite informative.